# how to work backwards in a function in R

Tags: r, function

I was wondering if it would be possible to work backwards in a function in R in order to get a value for a variable that will output a **known** value.

For a simple example,

```
x<-5

afunction <- function(x,y) {
    x*y
}
```

How can I get the value of `y` that will output a **known** value of say `15`. That is, I want the the return of the function to be `3`.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming you meant y=3 and then x*y = 15. Set a default in the arg-list: `afunction <- function(x,y=3) {
    x*y
}`. If that not what you meant then simple division

Comment: @BondedDust I was under impression OP is looking for an inverse function.

Comment: @BondendDust, yes @zero323 is correct. This is just a simplified example, my actual code is quite involved, but is the same underlying principle. Here, I don't know the value of `y`, but I know that the value of `x*y` should be `15`

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the `y` value that makes `afunction(x, y)` equal 15, this is the same as finding the zeros of the following function:

```
g <- function(y) afunction(x, y) - 15
```

You can use `uniroot` to find zeros of a function:

```
uniroot(g, c(-100, 100))$root
# [1] 3
```

Note that you need to specify a range of `y` values for `uniroot` -- I've used [-100, 100] here.

Comment: Thanks for your response $josiber, I just have one question: When do this for different functions, sometimes I get the error: `Error in uniroot(n, c(-100, 100)) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign` -- do you how to fix this?

Comment: @Rish try passing `extendInt="yes"` as an additional argument to `uniroot`, as suggested on the help page at `?uniroot`.

Comment: I tried this, but got: `error in uniroot(n, c(-100, 100), extendInt = "yes") : no sign change found in 1000 iterations`

Comment: @Rish are you certain that the function can output the specified value? `uniroot` tries to find input values that make the function fall above and below 0, so if your function doesn't achieve smaller and larger values you might not be able to use `uniroot`.